# Suppressing in the word "Chapter N" from header, documentclass: report

Tags: header-footer, report

I want to suppress the word "Chapter n" from my header. I want to have only the chapter title in the header e.g. "Introduction" not as "Chapter 1. Introduction"
The document class is report.
Here is the full code of my document;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bf}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge\bf}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=45mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage} 
\fancyfoot{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage{cite}
```

Comment: if i understand the question correctly, all you want to do is omit the "chapter n" from above the chapter title.  if that is true, then you can just use `\chapter*{...}` (the asterisk * gives the instruction to omit the number from the heading).  with the `report` class, this also omits the entry for the chapter from the table of contents, but that can be added back explicitly with `\addcontentsline`.  (search for that in other questions.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the chapter name in the header line in all-caps, insert the instruction

```
\def\chaptermark#1{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
```

in the preamble.

If you do *not* want the chapter name rendered in all-caps, use the instruction

```
\def\chaptermark#1{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

Comment: Note that the proposed solution method is specific to the `report` document class. Other solutions may be needed if one uses other document classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want, it's easy to do with `titleps`, a companion to `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=45mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{ownstyle}{%
\sethead[\thesection. ~\MakeUppercase{\sectiontitle}][][\thepage]{\thepage}{}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}
\setfoot{}{}{}
\headrule
}
\pagestyle{ownstyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{A first section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]